# Criar um atalho da aplicação em um onLogClickListener?

Tags: java, android

O código abaixo, cria um atalho na tela inicial do aparelho, mas ao clicar neste atalho, ele me retorna um erro "O app não está instalado"
Como resolver? 
Gostaria que esta mainactivity fosse aberta com parametro especifico, para disparar um evento ao ser aberta por este atalho criado.

Segue abaixo o código utilizado:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

fabEmergencia.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        createShortCut();
        return true;
    }
});


private void createShortCut() {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activity,MainActivity.class);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    shortcutIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    Intent addIntent = new Intent();
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "YourAppName");
    addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(activity, R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    activity.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geralmente quando uso, faço desta forma abaixo:

```
public void criarAtalho(){
    // cria intent para criar atalho
    Intent shortcutintent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
    // nega atalho repetido
    shortcutintent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
    // define um nome para o atalho
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Nome do atalho");
    // define do icone do atalho
    Parcelable icon = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);
    // define atividade que será iniciada ao clicar no atalho
    shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(getApplicationContext() , MainActivity.class));
    // envia broadcast
    sendBroadcast(shortcutintent);
}
```

Aí no método `setOnLongClickListener`, você faz desta forma abaixo:

```
fabEmergencia.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        criarAtalho();
        return true;
    }
});
```

E como você já comentou na questão, deves dar permissão no `AndroidManifest`. Veja:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT"/>
```

Abaixo como deve estar sua `<activity>` no `AndroidManifest`:

```
<activity 
    android:name=".MainActivity" 
    android:label="@string/title"
    .
    .
    .
    >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: O erro acontece, ele cria o atalho, mas ao clicar neste atalho aparece "O app não está instalado"

Comment: Aqui comigo funciona normalmente! Seu intent está apontado para classe principal?

Comment: Sim, está apontando para MainActivity. Mas o botão também está na MainActivity. shortcutintent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));

Comment: Entendi meu erro, a launcher, é uma splashactvity, ela deve ser chamada. :/

Comment: @HenriqueMendes exatamente isso que eu ia falar!